# When i change db postgres to mysql,Its showing Django 2026, SSL connection error

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I change my database postgres to sql ,Now its showing ssl error

Nothing expect or try, just need answer , so thank you

Answer (score 0):

Paste following command in setting (**init.py**)file

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```